# What does $\Bbb E[X|Y]\Bbb E[Y]$ simplify to?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

**My Goal**

I am trying to figure out what $\Bbb E[X|Y]\Bbb E[Y]$ simplifies to.

**My Work So Far**

I have the following train of thought

$$\Bbb E[X|Y] = \sum_i x_i \Bbb P(X=x_i|Y=y_j)$$
$$\Bbb E[Y] = \sum_j y_j \Bbb P(Y=y_j)$$

Taking these and multiplying

\begin{align}
\Bbb E[X|Y] \Bbb E[Y] & = \left(\sum_i x_i \Bbb P(X=x_i|Y=y_j)\right)\left( \sum_j y_j \Bbb P(Y=y_j)\right)\\
&= \sum_j \sum_i x_i y_j \Bbb P(X=x_i|Y=y_j)\Bbb P(Y=y_j)\\
&= \sum_j \sum_i x_i y_j \Bbb P(X=x_i) \\
&= \sum_j y_j \Bbb E[X]
\end{align}

But this isn't very elegant, so I feel like this can't be right.

**My Question**

Am I on the right track? If so, what are the steps I am missing? If not, why and how should I approach this?

Edit:

I think I may have made a simple mistake.

I think it should probably be

\begin{align}
\Bbb E[X|Y] \Bbb E[Y] & = \left(\sum_i x_i \Bbb P(X=x_i|Y=y_j)\right)\left( \sum_j y_j \Bbb P(Y=y_j)\right)\\
&= \sum_j \sum_i x_i y_j \Bbb P(X=x_i|Y=y_j)\Bbb P(Y=y_j)\\
&= \sum_i x_i \Bbb P(X=x_i) \\
&= \Bbb E[X]
\end{align}

Comment: The RHS of your first identity for $\Bbb E[X|Y]$ is not $\Bbb E[X|Y]$ but $\Bbb E[X|Y=y_j]$, hence the rest of your considerations falls. Note that $\Bbb E[X|Y]$ is a *random variable*, not a number like expectations are. Finally, the answer to the question in your title is: *Not much*, and anyway, nothing interesting in the general case.

Comment: Further more, $~\mathsf E(X\mid Y=y_\color{blue}{j})~\sum_\color{crimson}{j} y_j~\mathsf P(Y=y_\color{crimson}{j}) ~\neq~ \sum_\color{crimson}{j} \mathsf E(X\mid Y=y_\color{crimson}{j})~y_\color{crimson}{j}~\mathsf P(Y=y_\color{crimson}{j})~$  You cannot comute a particular instance of $j$-value *into* the scope of the $j$-indexed series.